# Truffle.js and Kovan/Ropsten

Tags: truffle, ropsten, kovan

I am trying to use truffle.js and the testnet. I want to test using Kovan an Ropsten. Here is the doc from truffle -

```
networks: {
  "live": {
network_id: 1, // Ethereum public network
// optional config values
// host - defaults to "localhost"
// port - defaults to 8545
// gas
// gasPrice
// from - default address to use for any transaction Truffle makes   during migrations
  },
  "morden": {
   network_id: 2,        // Official Ethereum test network
host: "178.25.19.88", // Random IP for example purposes (do not use)
port: 80
 },
  "staging": {
network_id: 1337 // custom private network
// use default rpc settings
  },
  "development": {
    network_id: "default"
 }
```

}

But it does not state about Kovan or what should be used for the host IP address. Does anyone have any details about this?

I am trying to use -

```
truffle migrate --network kovan
```

I have ubuntu 14.04 and the latest truffle (3.x) and the latest geth.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know Kovan is only accessible by running [Parity](https://github.com/paritytech/parity). This repo contains all of the info and instructions on getting Kovan setup along with the config file: https://github.com/kovan-testnet/config

As for integration with Truffle, if you're running parity locally you could use the standard localhost:8545, and the network id: 42

I would also recommend looking at this [repo](https://github.com/kovan-testnet/proposal) which discusses more of the specifics of the project. For example, since Kovan uses proof-of-authority, regular users aren't capable of validating blocks (and thus earning Ether), so you will need to use a faucet (discussed in the link) to fund an address.

Comment: I also just noticed in the latest MetaMask they have a public RPC node:
https://kovan.infura.io/metamask